# How can I cast a TinyInt value from a SQL Server Table?

Tags: c#, sql-server-express, data-conversion, tinyint

I have this SQL Server (Express) table:

[image]

...with a GenreId of TinyInt (there will only be a few dozen distinct Genres, at most).

This C# code is failing, with "Specified cast is not valid."

```
int genreId = 0;
. . .
genreId = GetGenreIdForGenre(_genre);
```

The value of "_genre" at the point of failure is "Adventure". The call to GetGenreIdForGenre() should return "1":

[image]

This is the line that fails, in GetGenreIdForGenre():

```
return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

In context, the GetGenreIdForGenre() method is:

```
private int GetGenreIdForGenre(string genre)
{
    try
    {
        string qry = "SELECT GenreId FROM dbo.GENRES WHERE Genre = @genre";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre", genre);
                connection.Open();
                return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         return 0;
     }
 }
```

There is no (TinyInt) conversion available. Int32 also failed. What do I need to do to retrieve the TinyInt value?

Comment: Did you try understanding the error message that code will throw?
Because I am fairly certain it contains all the info you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`command.ExecuteScalar`'s return type is `object` so the value it's returning a boxed `byte`.  Before you can cast it to `int`, you have to unbox the `byte`:

```cs
return (byte)reader.ExecuteScalar();
```

After the unboxing cast to `byte`, it will use the available implicit conversion to `int` (to match the method's return type) so you don't need another cast.

Answer (score 2):

Cast it on the query:

```
string qry = "SELECT CAST(GenreId as int) FROM dbo.GENRES WHERE Genre = @genre";
```

That way you won't need to worry about client side conversions.

Comment: Thanks Athanasios, I didn't know about that; however, I get a compilation error on the C# code without a cast.